# Is it possible plot using ordered dictionary or list, OrderedDict doesn't work

Tags: python, dictionary, plot

I want to plot temperature decreasing  in time. The calculation is correct, my problem is that dictionary can NOT be in order. I can sorted list in time. keys=time(1year,5year, 10year etc), values=temperature. I want sort by keys

```
drawtemperature={}
for i, tau in enumerate(years):
    for well in producers :
        Temperature=[]
            if len(reached) == 0:
                Temperature.append(T0)
            else: 
                 sumQ=well.flow/nbcontours*len(reached)
                 Tm=((well.flow-sumQ)*T0+sumQ*Ti)/well.flow
                 Temperature.append(Tm)   

           drawtemperature[tau]=Temperature

dc=[drawtemperature[k] for k in sorted(drawtemperature)]

for k in dc:
    pylab.plot(drawtemperature.keys(), drawtemperature.values())
pylab.show()
```

It drawing in wrong way, because of not ordering dictionary. The figure should be a piston like. I couldn't post images, because I need at least 10 reputation(:

I know that I can't order dictionary, I've alreday tried OrderedDict from collection, but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? I assume you are trying to sort the dictionary by value

```
pylab.plot(*zip(*sorted(dc.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])))
```

To switch the axes use this

```
pylab.plot(*reversed(zip(*sorted(dc.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]))))
```

To sort by key, just leave the `key=...` out

Comment: I want to sort be keys, by time

Comment: i would have said the sort should be on the key rather than on the value. (in which case, the lambda would be unnecessary)